# SimpleExoPlayerView customization to keep background transparent and controls always visible

Tags: android, android-layout, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm using `ExoPlayer` to play audio songs, here is how my `SimpleExoPlayerView` looks like:

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
  android:id="@+id/video_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Requirement:**

1. How to keep `SimpleExoPlayerView` background as *transparent*, instead of **Black background** [as still, I'm getting] (see above *Screenshot*)
2. How to keep `SimpleExoPlayerView` always *visible* (as still it appears and then disappear, until I touch again)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set `show_timeout` to 0 to avoid controls being hidden (also might want to set `hide_on_touch` to false as well)

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
           android:id="@+id/video_view"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           app:show_timeout="0"
           app:hide_on_touch="false"
           app:controller_layout_id="@layout/exo_playback_control_view" />
```

You can also define your own `controller_layout_id` layout which should give you all the control you need over background etc (can use default one as starting point).

Comment: I tried using custom_layout but still getting black as background

Comment: Did you make changes to custom layout to specify use of transparent background?

Comment: one thing I just noticed, all the buttons are working except play and pause, like playing a song, still pause button is visible, now trying to do tap on it, to pause it, but click is not responding WHY and HOW TO RESOLVE IT ?

Comment: @Sophie not sure tbh....am using above code here as well and not seeing that issue.  Is there a chance that it's disabled in the layout xml you have?

Answer (score 1):

In reference to the "keep background transparent" aspect of this question, you may be setting the background of the controls background as transparent, but still seeing a black background on your playback control view.

Reason being....it's not your controls background that's black.

**It's the darn shutterView in the layout that's still visible / has a black color background**

To change in XML add the following attribute to your PlayerView xml:

```
app:shutter_background_color="@color/transparent"
```

To remove the view entirely you can do:

```
((ViewGroup)shutterView.getParent()).removeView(shutterView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code on your onCreate() method:

```
 int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("exo_shutter", "id", getPackageName());
 findViewById(resId).setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.transparent));
```